# SP2010, how to add email address validation to a column?

Tags: validation

I have the following code:

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND("@";[emailAddressField]))
```

It's not working, can someone recommend a better formula.

Thank you!

The exact problem is... depending on the default site language the ; character needs to at times be , while at other times ;

I'm looking for a language agnostic formula that works with all site languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that it should be "," instead of ";" in `=ISNUMBER(FIND("@",[emailAddressField]))` at [Examples of common formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA010105479.aspx#BM4) and I think that something like calculated fields in SHarePoint are language agnostic for all.

Hope it'll help.

[**Update**]
If you need validation you can here is an [article](http://spdeveloper.net/tag/input-masks/) how to use jquery input plugin. In that case user will have to put valid email address.

Comment: unfortunately they're not language agnostic. ; works in Czech site, while , works in an English site. Crazy I know....

Comment: So you want to prevent user from entering wrong e-mail? Why not to use input mask in that case?

Comment: I want to use validation on the column. So far we have a theory it is because SP uses Excel validation, and this is language dependent, the functions actually change depending on the language of the site. But its a theory at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem, it IS language dependend, even the formula names change :-S. We circumvented this using jQuery: bind to the checkbox's onblur, if invalid, show message and disable ok button